# can we use Empty XSD ComplexType(Base) in Extension under Complex content in Child ComplexType?

Tags: xml, xsd

In Below XSD Format, is it the best way to use ObjectType in the Extension?? Do We really required in any aspect..any one help on this. shall i remove this objectType extension inside message..??

```
***<complexType name="ObjectType"/>***
<complexType name="Message">
        <complexContent>
            ***<extension base="ObjectType">***
                <sequence>
                <element name="element1" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                </element>
                </sequence>
                </extension>
        </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This XSD is correct (semantically and syntactically). I validate also by [XMLSpear](http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://yourNamespace"
    xmlns="http://yourNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="ObjectType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="Message">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ObjectType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_extension.asp) there are examples of extensions. http://www.w3schools.com/

---

Solution without extension

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://yourNamespace"
        xmlns="http://yourNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


        <xs:complexType name="Message">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks Zstian. But i see many xsd extending empty base like this.. My question is it mandatory to extend in complexContent like this ? or we can eliminate this extension tag! if i remove this, would it impact anything in my application??

Comment: it was a pleasure to help you :)

Comment: @Mohu this topic is open yet, are there other information that you needed?